# Java regex - How to read numbers only 5 to 7 digits

Tags: java, regex

I have following now.

```
regex=^[0-9]{6}$
```

this is working for starting 0 to 9 and for 6 and 7 digit number.

Please suggest how can i add for 5, 6 and 7 digit numbers.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

use the range form of the `{ }` operator

```
^[0-9]{5,7}$
```

Range inside of `{N,M}` is demarcated with a comma and translates into a string with length between `N` and `M` inclusive.

This is notably different from the `[ ]` operator which is to describe a character group and uses the `-` symbol to demarcate its ranges.

Comment: How to allow 5 or 9 number of digits only?

Answer (score 6):

`^[0-9]{5,7}$` should do the job for you if I understood your question correctly also your regex `^[0-9]{6}$` will match **exactly** 6 digits not *6 or 7* as you stated.

Comment: not sure what value this answer adds...I think it's been sufficiently answered already.

Comment: @mre: When I was typing it didn't have other answer, now I see it was answered before me so I will delete mine.

Comment: Do NOT delete you're answer!  Leave it.

Comment: @Keng, OK I will not delete it :)